# how to reload an instance of a domain class from a database grails?

Tags: sql, grails, refresh, reload

I have 4 objects (instances of domain classes) called taxi, placed in an object called moveRequest under a property allocatedTaxi.

The classes look like this:

```
class MoveRequest{

Taxi allocatedTaxi
Zone destinationZone
Integer destination
String microDestination
String targetType = ""
String targetName = ""
Zone currentTaxiZone
Taxi obstructingTaxi
Taxi boardedTaxi

String state = "pending"
Boolean requestedSpecific
Date dateCreated

static constraints = {
    currentTaxiZone(nullable: true)
    obstructingTaxi(nullable: true)
    boardedTaxi(nullable: true)
}

static mapping = {
    version false
}
```

}

```
class Taxi {

String name
Integer position
Double voltage
Boolean busy
Integer orderNumber

static belongsTo = [rail: Rail]

static mapping = {
    version false
}

static constraints = {
    name blank: false
}
```

}

Now, while iterating over moveRequests i update position properties of the taxi objects using an sql statement in a function like this:

```
def updateTaxiPosition(def taxiName, def millimeters){
    def config = grailsApplication.config
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(config.grails.databaseURL, config.grails.databaseUsername, config.grails.databasePassword, config.grails.databaseDriverClassName)

    sql.getConnection().setAutoCommit(true)
    sql.execute("UPDATE taxi SET position= ? WHERE name = ?", [millimeters, taxiName])
    sql.close()
}
```

Now, the other way to do this would be to use this line of code:

```
moveRequest.allocatedTaxi.position = millimeters
```

But, since i need to update it fast im using the direct sql, because it automatically updates taxi position. Now the problem arrises when i try to access the changed position. I can only access the old position, even though the position has changed in the database, and when i try to do this:

```
println("taxi position: " + moveRequest.allocatedTaxi.position)
```

i get the old value before updating the position property. Now i have tried to refresh the moveRequest instance like this:

```
def refreshMoveRequestInformation(def moveRequest){
    def config = grailsApplication.config
    def sql = Sql.newInstance(config.grails.databaseURL, config.grails.databaseUsername, config.grails.databasePassword, config.grails.databaseDriverClassName)

    sql.getConnection().setAutoCommit(true)
    def row = sql.rows("SELECT * FROM taxi WHERE id=?", [moveRequest.allocatedTaxi.id])
    println("row -> taxi name: " + row.name + ", taxi position: " + row.position)
    sql.close()

    def newPosition = null
    row.each{
        newPosition = it.position
    }
    moveRequest.allocatedTaxi.position = newPosition
}
```

and also like this:

```
def refreshMoveRequestInformation(def moveRequest){
    def taxi = Taxi.get(moveRequest.allocatedTaxi.id)
    println("1 - new taxi name: " + taxi.name + ", taxi position: " + taxi.position)
    taxi.refresh()
    println("2 - new taxi name: " + taxi.name + ", taxi position: " + taxi.position)

    println("move request -> taxi name: " + moveRequest.allocatedTaxi.name + ", taxi position: " + moveRequest.allocatedTaxi.position)

    return moveRequest
}
```

but none of it seems to work. I keep getting the old value, even though the row instance shows the new one. How can i update the moveRequest instance (by that i mean reload from database) it's allocatedTaxi property (or more precisely, the position property)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you can do.

First, calling [.refresh()](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/refresh.html) on your domain instance will ensure it's loaded from the SOR (system of record), your database in this case.

Second, you may want to remove this domain class from Hibernates second level [cache](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Database%20Mapping/cache.html).

```
class SomeClass {
  static mapping = {
    cache false
  }
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that i dont think the refresh() works, because when it is called on the taxi instance, it just returns the same value before the update has been executed. I dont understand why, it's like it remembers its value when entering in a transaction, and then simply using that same value no matter what happens in the database.

Comment: Try removing it from Hibernates cache as well. It's entirely possible if you are in a transaction that the update is isolated. What's the scope of the transaction?

Comment: so i should try adding cache false to the taxi class? i'm not sure how this would help, would you mind explaining? i belive the scope of the transaction would be for the entire function that manages the moveRequests, since all of the functions are placed in a service, so changes made using the other line (moveRequest.allocatedTaxi.position = millimeters) are seen in the databse only after all 4 instances have been updated using that line, ergo the iterating over the 4 moveRequests has finished. sorry if i complicated that more than i should xD

Comment: There are two things going on. Setting the cache to false will make sure that Hibernate does not try and cache the instance. Second, the transaction isolation level by Grails services may be playing into your case here. What database are you using? I/You will need to research what the isolation level is for that database by default. It's possible that your update isn't being seen since the transaction is still active (e.g. not committed) and the isolation level doesn't allow for dirty reads.

Comment: Shouldn't this fix that the not commited problem? sql.getConnection().setAutoCommit(true)

Comment: i'm using mysql database.

Comment: Okay, it's important to understand that Grails services are transactional by default. If you haven't set the isolation level in the service, or changed the default for your database it's going to be READ_COMMITED. However, looking at the way you are getting a connection to the database it's possible you are getting a connection OUTSIDE of the transaction used by Grails (provided by the proxied datasource). The only other suggestion I can make is to inject the dataSource bean into your service and get a connection to the database using def sql = new Sql(dataSource) instead.

Comment: Some further reading about data sources and such in Grails: http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/conf.html#transactionAwareDataSourceProxy